# HTC One M8 Charging Issues

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life, htc, htc-one-m8

I just wanted to check if my HTC One M8 is working fine, I just got it and it's brand new but the battery runs out in 4 hours of non stop use and mobile data usage and when I charge it, it charges at about 1% every 5-10 minutes, is this normal? And if not how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The charging issue may be caused thanks to some app which is running on background and a lot burdens CPU.

```
Try to kill all apps before/while charging to decrease CPU consumption
```

That 4 hours of nonstop usage are normal I think. If you were playing games or something like that you should be happy for 4 hours. :) So answer is: Yes, It's normal.

Look at [this guide](http://www.htc.com/us/support/htc-one-m8/howto/464911.html)

Comment: How do I kill the apps before charging?

Comment: In multitask menu you can swipe to right or left to kill app. I do not own M8 so I don't know.

You can also use task manager

Comment: @PuppetCode you can also go into the app manager and individually disable apps you don't ever want to run. This will stop them from running again in the background when you restart your phone or when they just decide to run